# Babel + Typescript + NPM Modules + Webpack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, webpack

Hello I try to require angular from my typescript script, and I get this error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular'.
```

Here is my webpack config file:

```
    context: __dirname + '/client/js',
    entry: './script.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js',
        path: options.BUILD ? 'dist' : 'dev'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.ts(x?)$/, loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader'}
        ]
    }
```

EDIT:

Then, in my script.ts file, I do:

```
import angular from 'angular';
```

or even
    var angular = require('angular');

gives me the same result

I don't have any tsconfig.json file

Thank you !

Comment: that webpack config file doesn't tell us anything about where angular might be, where you are trying to use it, or the relationship between those two factors.

Comment: Can you also put your tsconfig.json ?

Comment: I'm trying to use it in my script.ts file 

    import angular from 'angular';

or 
    var angular = require('angular');
gives me the same result

and I don't have any tsconfig.json file, do I need one ?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have any tsconfig.json file

You need a tsconfig.json file. See ts-loader readme : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#configuration

## Example with babel

Checkout : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/93

Answer (score 0):

first in your terminal type `tsc --init`
then add to `types` array in `tsconfig.json` angular declaration
the last thing you have to do is import all from angular `import * as angular from "angular"`. You can use angular declaration e.g `$location: angular.ILocationService`